# Errors while joining two tables using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

When I tried to join two tables I got the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object:
>  sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Join at 0x7f31a35b02e8; Join object on
>   chanel(139851192912136) and Device(139851192912864)

My code is:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import and_,or_,not_,inspect,text,inspection
engine = db.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://sa:elnetsrv@192.108.55.95/ELNetDB")
Data1 = db.Table("chanel", metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
Data2 = db.Table("Device",metadata,autoload = True,autoload_with = engine)
metadata = db.MetaData()
j = Data1.join(Data2,Data1.columns.No == Data2.columns.ID)
print(engine.execute(j))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data1.join(Data2,Data1.columns.No == Data2.columns.ID)` is not executable because it is not a query object.

You can try this instead (assuming you want to select every column from Data1):

```
print( engine.execute(select([Data1]).select_from(j) )
```

see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.join for reference.